# Difference in resource closing

Tags: java

When I open resource in main method

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
```

Eclipse shows me warning `Resource leak: 'webClient' is never closed`. So I need to close resource by

```
webClient.close().
```

But when I get `WebClient` from method

```
WebClient webClient = getWebCLient()

public static WebClient getWebClient() {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    ...
    return webClient;
}
```

I'm not receiving such an warning. Why?

Comment: Because the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out the client is never closed.

Comment: That mean problem still exist, only IDE doesn't tell me about it.Is using `try(WebClient webClient = getWebClient()){...` a correct solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE isn't smart enough to warn you in this case. By no way it means that the `WebClient` has not to be closed anymore.

If `WebClient` implements [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) consider, as a good practice, to wrap the call to `getWebClient()` into a try-with-resource for automatic closing

```
try (WebClient wc = getWebClient()) {
    ...
}
```